# How to force file to download which is output of json file

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
$details1=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/download/download.json"));
$details2=json_decode(file_get_contents($details1->data));
echo "{$details2->data}";
?>
```

I do found some php code there i can force file to download but, i want to connect it with the result of download.json to be forced downloading.

Forece downloading example:

```
$file_url = 'http://www.test.com/forece-file.mp3';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . 
basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: Just put the `header()` lines from the second block above your code in the first block.

Comment: @Mike  Could give me an example? i tried it, but still not any respons :O

Comment: First, [get errors to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). Do you get any output at all? Does the `echo` line above work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents` like this:

```
<?php
$details1=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/download/download.json"), true);
$details2=json_decode(file_get_contents($details1['data']), true);

$file_url = $details2['data'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . 
basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
?>
```

Or you can use cURL:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://2strok.com/download/download.json";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$url2 = json_decode($output)->data;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$url3 = json_decode($output)->data;

curl_close($ch);     

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($url3) . "\"");
readfile($url3);
?>
```

Comment: It's not giving me any respons :/

Comment: You're trying to send headers after echoing content.

Comment: I think you didn't got my question :P

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria Hey bro, i do have one more question from you. The code that you fixed is getting error like: Warning: file_get_contents(url): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 

Sombody recommended curl php for me to use it, but i don't really have any idea how. 

Do you think u can find some solution for it? Thx

Comment: @Zabi, I added the cURL answer for you. Please check.

Comment: 401 error is unauthorize.. Did you change any settings on your PHP or webserver? I can simply run both scripts without any trouble.

Comment: in which php version?

Comment: Please take a look :)

http://2strok.com/download/Screen%20Shot%202018-02-28%20at%2017.04.38.png

Comment: I guess it's working but, not forcing to download :P